# Change source file from dynamic scheduling to static scheduling

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to change the following C source code to static scheduling, but I don't know how it's done. I've tried to `static`before `#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)`:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
int nthreads, tid;


/* Fork a team of threads giving them their own copies of variables */
static #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid) //I tried it here
  {

  /* Obtain thread number */
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();
  printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

  /* Only master thread does this */
  if (tid == 0) 
    {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
    }

  }  /* All threads join master thread and disband */

}
```

What I expect is that thread 0 gets the first chunk, thread 1 the second chunk, and so on. However, it's randomly now as it's dynamically

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads,tid) schedule(static)`

Comment: When I try to compile it, it says: `‘schedule’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp parallel’
 #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads,tid) schedule(static)
`

Comment: Oops, my bad, I hadn't notice you have no `for` loop. The `schedule` directive only applies for an `omp for` directive. So in essence, your question of scheduling doesn't make any sense with the code snippet you provided

Comment: Now it says : `world.c:12:45: error: ‘for’ must be the first clause of ‘#pragma omp parallel’
 #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid) for schedule(static)
                                             ^
world.c:12:45: error: ‘for’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp parallel’
world.c:12:49: error: ‘schedule’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp parallel’
 #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid) for schedule(static)`
                                                 ^

Comment: you need a `for` loop somewhere. You haven't any such loop to distribute work across threads so you cannot define the type of scheduling for distributing it. Add a `for` loop somewhere inside your `parallel` region, decorate it with `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` and that will work

Comment: As @Gilles mentioned the static scheduling is only for loops.